# Get civiMail report by API

Tags: civimail, api, reports

I'm trying to get Report data about a Sent email through the API. I can see the report at:

`www.example.com/civicrm/mailing/report?mid=388&reset=1`

And I can get data corresponding to the email from the API explorer as follows:

[image: API explorer get civiMail]

But I can't seem to access the civiMail report with the API. I have tried a few options but can't seem to find it. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `ReportTemplate.getrows` API call.  You can see examples of its use in the API explorer's built-in help (also available [on Github](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/examples/ReportTemplate/Getrows.php)).  More examples exist in the [tests folder](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/api/v3/ReportTemplateTest.php), since the most common use of this API is to create tests for reports.

UPDATE: As @demerit points out, this answer isn't really correct - but it CAN be :)  All(?) of the info on this mailing report is also available from the "Mailing Summary" report (for the stats) and the "Mailing Detail" report (if you need drilled-down data on click-throughs etc.).  So I recommend Demerit's answer if you're writing an extension, but my answer if you need to collect this data over REST.

Comment: I don't know if this phrase has ever been said before but "Jon this answer might be wrong?". The mailing report here isn't a CiviReport it's a (CRM_XXX_)Page. Yes there are various mailing reports you can get from ReportTemplate.getrows but I don't think the one in question.

Comment: @Demerit Good points.  I updated my answer to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to do something like this:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Mailing/Page/Report.php#L107-L110

For the $this variable, you can probably use a dummy, e.g.

`$page = new CRM_Mailing_Page_Report();
$page->_mailing_id = 388; // or whatever number
$report = CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::report($page->_mailing_id);
CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::getMailingContent($report, $page);`

Lower down it assigns $report to the smarty template, and you can see how it's used at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Mailing/Page/Report.tpl, so you should be able to do the same thing in php, accessing the member elements of $report.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that would work.

Is it possible to achieve what you describe in the API explorer?

Comment: I'm not completely sure that you CAN'T do it from the api, but the functionality seems partly tied to the page. I've updated answer a bit.